# What Swing control to use to choose from "big data"?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to ask what swing control to use in case below.

I am working on some school project and developing application for digital evolution. There will be big number of processes and I would like to chose only single one. For this one I will draw a graph.

I think `JComboBox` is not the good solution, because there could be many processes (like hundreds). What is the best way for this selection?

Comment: My guess would be a `JTable` wrapped in a `JScrollPane`. Now, hundreds of objects remains nothing for the UI. Your question is awfully broad to provide an actual objective answer.

Comment: "100" is everything, but "big data". This is basically more of an optical/user interface question then a swing-related question? Your question is less "which swing class to use", more "which type of widget is appropriate for this type of application?".

Comment: I meant there could be hundreds, but thousands and tens of thousands of processes. And sorry for big data, It should be rather big volume of data..

Comment: *"I meant there could be hundreds, but thousands and tens of thousands.."*  How are you supposed to present to the user 10s of thousands of choices and make it in any way workable (for the user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for **Paging or pagable JTable(Table) Model for large data set**

**JScrollPane** will help you out for scrolling around records

[image: Paged JTable]

[Here is a tutorial about how to achieve it](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/PagingorpagableJTableTableModelforlargedataset.htm)

Comment: this seems to me like a good possibility to get what I want! Many thanks to you!

Comment: If this solves your problem , then [Accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , So that others may know that the issue has been resolved .